# how to display two digits after decimal point in a calculated column in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, decimal

```
 select *, 
        (TotalDeaths/TotalCases)*100 as PercentDeath, 
        (TotalDeaths/population)*100 as DeathPercentPopulation
from ( select location, 
              population, 
              sum(newcases) as TotalCases, 
              sum(newdeaths) as TotalDeaths
      from deaths
      where continent is not null
      group by location
     ) as newtable
order by DeathPercentPopulation desc
```

There several digits after decimal in "PercentDeath" and "DeathPercentPopulation" column. However I just want to display two digit after decimal. How can I do that without nesting this query again?

[image]

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? (sql server, mysql, postgres, snowflake, oracle, etc)?

Comment: As i can see he use MS SQL Server

Comment: How exactly do you see it?

Comment: I am using MySQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [TRUNCATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_truncate)

> TRUNCATE(X,D)
>
> Returns the number X, truncated to D decimal places. If D is 0, the
> result has no decimal point or fractional part. D can be negative to
> cause D digits left of the decimal point of the value X to become
> zero.

Something like this:

```
select *, 
        TRUNCATE((TotalDeaths/TotalCases)*100,2) as PercentDeath, 
        TRUNCATE((TotalDeaths/population)*100,2) as DeathPercentPopulation
from ( select location, 
              population, 
              sum(newcases) as TotalCases, 
              sum(newdeaths) as TotalDeaths
      from deaths
      where continent is not null
      group by location
     ) as newtable
order by DeathPercentPopulation desc
```

Or you could use `ROUND` function.

> The ROUND() function in MySQL is used to round a number to a specified
> number of decimal places. If no specified number of decimal places is
> provided for round off, it rounds off the number to the nearest
> integer.
>
> Syntax :
>
> ROUND(X, D) Parameter : This method accepts two parameters in the
> syntax, as mentioned above and described below –
>
> X : The number which to be rounded. D : Number of decimal places up to
> which the given number is to be rounded. It is optional. If not given
> it round off the number to the closest integer. If it is negative,
> then the number is rounded to the left side of the decimal point.

```
select *, 
        ROUND((TotalDeaths/TotalCases)*100,2) as PercentDeath, 
        ROUND((TotalDeaths/population)*100,2) as DeathPercentPopulation
from ( select location, 
              population, 
              sum(newcases) as TotalCases, 
              sum(newdeaths) as TotalDeaths
      from deaths
      where continent is not null
      group by location
     ) as newtable
order by DeathPercentPopulation desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `FORMAT()` function instead of `ROUND` or `TRUNCATE`.  It is designed for this.  It also puts in 'thousands separators' based on the Locale.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the ROUND() function : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Use case :

```
select *, 
        (ROUND(TotalDeaths/TotalCases)*100, 2) as PercentDeath), 
        (ROUND(TotalDeaths/population)*100, 2) as DeathPercentPopulation)
FROM ...
```

Comment: how exactly  can I use it? can you please instruct me.